# Emacs - select text by regexp (and idealy with option to select text only if regexp match is surrounding caret

Tags: emacs, elisp

I need to select text in Emacs with regexp. And it would be for the best if I had an option to match only if match is surrounding caret.

Example:

```
text.....

<start oftext I want to select> text.....
text....
text.... <caret> text....
text....
text.... <end of text I want to select>

some other text
```

Edit: I am sorry that I obviously didn't state my question clearly, so here is a clarification:

- Caret was meant as the place where cursor is currently placed, not literal text to  be matched
- Start and end of text to be selected is just all the text that is in the document without any empty line.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you want.  An example would help.

Comment: What do you mean with "select"? Placing point and mark? Do you want to do that interactively or in ELisp?

Comment: Select text between start and end via elisp. Cursor must be inside block to match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not hard to find something around point in elisp. Just use two searches, forward and backward.

```
(defun set-selection-around-parens()
  (interactive)
  (let ( (right-paren (save-excursion ; using save-excursion because
                                      ; we don't want to move the
                                      ; point.
                        (re-search-forward ")" nil t))) ; bound nil
                                                        ; no-error t
         (left-paren (save-excursion (re-search-backward "(" nil t))))
  (when (and right-paren left-paren)
    ;; this is actually a way to activate a mark
    ;; you have to move your point to one side
    (push-mark right-paren)
    (goto-char left-paren)
    (activate-mark))))
```

When you use primary selection to select something around, you can't save the position of your current point(you named it caret). To save current position and have some selection, you can use [secondary selection](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SecondarySelection).

```
(require 'second-sel)
(global-set-key [(control meta ?y)]     'secondary-dwim)
(define-key esc-map "y"                 'yank-pop-commands)
(define-key isearch-mode-map "\C-\M-y"  'isearch-yank-secondary)

(defun secondary-selection-deactivate()
  (interactive)
  (x-set-selection 'SECONDARY nil)
  (move-overlay mouse-secondary-overlay (point-min) (point-min) (current-buffer)))

(defun secondary-selection-in-this-buffer-p()
  (and (x-get-selection 'SECONDARY) (overlayp mouse-secondary-overlay) (eq (current-buffer) (overlay-buffer mouse-secondary-overlay))))

(defun set-secondary-selection-around-parens()
  (interactive)
  (let ( (right-paren (save-excursion (re-search-forward ")" nil t)))
         (left-paren (save-excursion (re-search-backward "(" nil t))))
  (when (and right-paren left-paren)
    (primary-to-secondary left-paren right-paren)
    )))
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not say how the start and end of the text to be selected are defined.  In fact, your question is *not clear at all*. If you just want to highlight all text that contains the literal text `<carat>`, then do this:

1. Use <kbd>M-s h r</kbd> to highlight a regexp. It prompts you for the regexp.
2. Type this regexp to match all text that contains the string `<carat>`:

```
\(.\|C-qC-j\)*<carat>\(.\|C-qC-j\)*
```

(If you meant the carat character, `^`, instead of the literal text `<carat>`, then replace that text above by `\^`.)

<kbd>C-q C-j</kbd> inserts a newline character.  The regexp `.` matches any character except newline, so the regexp `\(.\|C-qC-j\)` matches any character, including newline.

Comment: Based on your new question, try this: `M-s h r \(.+C-qC-j?\)+`, where `C-qC-j` is Control-Q followed by Control-J (which inserts a newline character.

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't directly answer your question, but depending on what you are actually selecting it may be best to use `mark-defun` or `mark-paragraph`.  There may even be something like `LaTeX-mark-environment` for the specific mode you are in.  If it's a new mode for a new type of file you can customize `paragraph-start`, `beginning-of-defun` or similar to get the desired results.  Of course if the regular expressions are input by the user this won't be a good option.